# Create checkbox for all line in php

Tags: php, fail2ban, zimbra

i want create a web console for list and unban Ip block by fail2ban. With this page i retrieve a list of banned ip. I want add checkbox for all ip. If checkbox is selected i want unban Ip with command fail2ban-client set zimbra unbanip $ip.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('sqlite3 /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3 "select ip,jail from bips"');
#$output = shell_exec('/var/www/html/list.sh');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I have this result:

```
111.206.250.197|zimbra
111.206.250.198|zimbra
111.206.250.229|zimbra
111.206.250.230|zimbra
117.50.7.159|zimbra
138.99.216.147|zimbra
141.98.80.87|zimbra
164.52.24.172|zimbra
178.211.57.114|zimbra
183.136.225.45|zimbra
185.156.172.49|zimbra
185.234.219.13|zimbra
193.169.252.208|zimbra
193.37.255.114|zimbra
195.78.210.4|zimbra
206.189.73.210|zimbra
45.150.206.113|zimbra
45.150.206.114|zimbra
45.150.206.115|zimbra
45.150.206.116|zimbra
45.150.206.117|zimbra
45.150.206.118|zimbra
45.150.206.119|zimbra
45.150.206.40|zimbra
45.227.255.233|zimbra
45.249.91.190|zimbra
47.104.151.39|zimbra
64.64.104.10|zimbra
78.128.113.67|zimbra
78.128.113.68|zimbra
79.58.62.241|zimbra
```

How I add a checkbox for unban ip? Have you same idea?
Thanks

Comment: You could explode on `|` I'd think then iterate on it and build HTML.

Answer (score 1):

For a better explanation on user3783243 comment :).

```
$output = shell_exec('sqlite3 /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3 "select ip,jail from 
bips"');
#$output = shell_exec('/var/www/html/list.sh');
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $output) as $line){
    $result = explode("|", $line);
    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$result[0]."'>";
    echo "<label> ".$line."</label><br>";
}
```

sample https://prnt.sc/wanvho
https://3v4l.org/J7DZd